# Как задокументировать, что метод возвращает self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, документация

У меня есть метод в классе, который возвращает self. Я решил задокументировать это, но понял, что не знаю что написать.

Допустим у меня есть класс 'MyCalss' с методом 'MyMethod'

```
class MyClass:

    def MyMethod(self, arg: int) -> ???:
        # Work
        return self
```

Я пытался вписать вместо `???` `self` и `MyClass`, но всегда появлялась ошибка `NameError`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 3.7+: `from __future__ import annotations`

В Python 3.7 добавили [PEP 563: postponed evaluation of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). Модуль, который импортировал `from __future__ import annotations` сохранит анотации автоматичкески:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Position:
    def __add__(self, other: Position) -> Position:
        ...
```

Это добавят в Python 3.10

### Python <3.7: use a string

[Следуя to PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), нужно использовать строки вместо классов:

```
class Position:
    ...
    def __add__(self, other: 'Position') -> 'Position':
       ...
```

[Тут подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/2101808)

Comment: В 3.11 планируется ввести специальную аннотацию Self: https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#specification.  `from __future__ import annotations` по умолчанию отложили до 3.11

Comment: *как минимум до 3.11, см. https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/25490#issuecomment-823623433

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> class MyClass:

    def my_method(self, arg: int) -> object:
        # Work
        return self

>>> myClass = MyClass()
>>> 
>>> rezult = myClass.my_method(7)
>>> print(rezult)
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000002FDE898>
```